# Hard to see hyperlinks?

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

I don't know if it's my monitor or bad eyesight, but do you guys/gals also have trouble seeing hyperlinks here at TCS? They almost have the same color as the text!

Comment: The other problem with moving it to meta is that hyperlinks are a different color on meta, which will create great confusion unless somebody points it out.

Comment: moved from parent site.

Comment: @Suresh: Did you move the question using your awesome mod powers, or did the community manage to move it by voting to close and selecting "this belongs on meta"?

Comment: I moved it :(. probably should have waited.

Comment: I was just curious to see if the community can move without mod intervention.

Comment: @Robin: A question is migrated with 5 votes even without moderator action.  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/migrate-questions-between-websites/

Comment: You may take a screenshot and show us what you see. This way, it's much easier to help you.

Answer (score 4):

While I don't have any major problems distinguishing the text and link colors, I do agree that it is a bit hard to distinguish them on a white background. I usually have to look carefully to check if there was a link buried in some text that I have overlooked.

I would support increasing the contrast between the two colors to make links stand out more.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have any problems distinguishing them on my laptop when my screen is turned on bright, but when it's turned down to its lowest setting, it's very hard; in between, it's not too difficult, but it could be easier.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it's your monitor.

Text is (almost) black and hyperlinks are red.

Answer (score 2):

We looked at this and just don't think it's worth any time investment.  The contrast against the background is high enough, and even against the regular text for ppl who can't see reds, there is what seems to us to be a fairly clear distinction.