# Contrast visited - unvisited hyperlinks

Tags: discussion, bug, status-declined, design

I know there’s been a [similar question](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/825/hard-to-see-hyperlinks), but I don’t actually have a problem with hyperlinks. I have a problem with the fact that the color for visited and unvisited links is almost the same, and so I have a really hard time distinguishing what questions have new answers.

Comment: They're different colors?????

Comment: Over at TCS SE, yes. Here it seems there’s no differentiation at all, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, they're supposed to be different colors. For questions on the parent site, unvisited questions have color #103f5f, while visited links are #306081. But they look the same to me.

Comment: I am not sure how a larger contrast between visited and unvisited hyperlinks tells you which questions have new answers.

Comment: The unvisited style is used for questions with no new answers, and the visited style for those with new answers.

Comment: @Sacha: That does not seem to happen to me.  On the top page, questions are shown with the unvisited color only if they are really unvisited.  I am using Firefox 3.6.13.  However, admittedly I usually visit questions which I am interested in when a new answer is posted to it, so this may not prove anything.

Comment: @Sacha: Please clarify what the problem is.  I am pretty sure that your description in the comment on Jan 2 18:38 is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Examples here at Meta:

- An [unvisited link](http://nonexistent.example.com/) (currently #83741E)
- A [visited link](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) (hopefully) (currently #A29131)

Comment: they look slightly different, but VERY slightly.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer so Community doesn't resurrect this question again.

Comment: @Peter: I think that it is good that this question was bumped, because at least the asker has not been convinced that the problem was nonexistent.

Answer (score 1):

The link colors look different enough, I think.

However, the [core premise here](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/856/contrast-visited-unvisited-hyperlinks#comment2417_856) (that we use visited/unvisited styles to indicate new answers on a post) is flawed. We don't.

With that in mind, I suggest keeping an eye on the questions list (sorted by active, so posts with new edits/answers/etc float to the top) instead of relying on the link color.